# Spray: routing - understand the difference between path and pathPrefix

Tags: scala, spray

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import spray.routing.HttpService
import spray.http._
import MediaTypes._
import spray.json._
import spray.routing.directives.CachingDirectives._
import spray.httpx.encoding._

trait MarginEvaluationService extends HttpService {
  import ClassSerializer._
  import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._
  val myRoute = {

      pathPrefix("hello") {
        get {
          respondWithMediaType(`text/html`) { // XML is marshalled to `text/xml` by default, so we simply override here
            complete {
              <html>
                <body>
                  <h1>Say hello to <i>spray-routing</i> on <i>spray-can</i>!</h1>
                </body>
              </html>
            }
          }
        }
      }
      ~
      pathPrefix("testjson") {
        get {
          entity(as[TestC]) { c =>
            respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
              complete(c)
            }
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

The [route](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/) is bugged:

> Error:(49, 1) illegal start of simple expression
>         pathPrefix("testjson") { ^

What is the difference between `path` and [`pathPrefix`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1.3/spray-routing/path-directives/pathPrefix/)?
I am not sure if the `~` operator is not properly included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/path-directives/index.html) :

**path(x)**: is equivalent to rawPathPrefix(slash().concat(segment(x)).concat(pathEnd())). It matches a leading slash followed by x and then the end.

**pathPrefix(x)**: is equivalent to rawPathPrefix(slash().concat(segment(x))). It matches a leading slash followed by x and then leaves a suffix unmatched.

Answer (score 12):

`path` is a final path, while `pathPrefix` can be subsequently combined with other path segments using the DSL.

If you want to match exactly `/hello` you should use `path("hello")`.

`pathPrefix` is convenient in cases like

```
pathPrefix("hello") {
  path("foo") {
    complete("foo")
  } ~
  path("bar") {
    complete("bar")
  }
}
```

which will match `/hello/foo` and `/hello/bar`.

---

That having being said, I suspect the error you're getting is simply the scala parser not getting along with the DSL.

Can you try moving the `~` on the same line as the closing brace?
I think the parser is inferring a semicolon, so it's really understanding that piece of code as

```
pathPrefix("hello") {
    get {
      respondWithMediaType(`text/html`) { // XML is marshalled to `text/xml` by default, so we simply override here
        complete {
          <html>
            <body>
              <h1>Say hello to <i>spray-routing</i> on <i>spray-can</i>!</h1>
            </body>
          </html>
        }
      }
    }
  };
  ~
  pathPrefix("testjson") {
    get {
      entity(as[TestC]) { c =>
        respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
          complete(c)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: it looks like I can not combine pathPrefix with `~`

Answer (score 0):

pathPrefix(x): This will add a slash before the unmatched (x). For ease of use, we do not have to include the slash in the directive. (Slash ~ x).

path(x): This will add a slash before the unmatched (x), will match (x) and then add a PathEnd. Unmatched path after (x), will be ignored. (Slash ~ x ~ PathEnd)